# How to use CryptUnprotectData to decrypt data encrypted by other users

Tags: dpapi

I want to decrypt the wireless network password, it's in the  of the xml file, how can I decrypt it in another user environment in the same computer.
Sorry for my bad English.

I have implemented decryption in the same user, now I need to decrypt in a different user. It would be great if the code can be given directly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.